# Python callback working with functions but not methods

Tags: python, callback

I have a third-party Python library that allows me to register a callback function that it called later.

While the code works okay with functions, when I tried to pass a method it fails, the callback is never called.

I have no control over the third party library (source code not available).

```
  def old_callbackFunction(param, data):
       print data

  class MyClass():
      def callbackFunction(self, param, data):
          print data

  myObj = MyClass()
  # old_setCallback(myObj.callbackFunction, param = "x") # this would work
  setCallback(myObj.callbackFunction, param = "x") # this is never called
```

Comment: I don't think I could give a precise answer without more information, but have you considered turning the method call into a function by wrapping it with a lambda expression or `functools.partial`?

Comment: I second @mlefavor's recommendation on investigating `functools.partial`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorin actually figured this out himself, with help from my comment, but he indicated that he wanted me to post the original comment as an answer. I was reluctant to post this originally because I'm unsure of the precise behavior of the setCallback and callbackFunction code; use at your own risk and modify as reason dictates.

The best way to wrap a function is to use `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial
setCallback(partial(myObj.callbackFunction), param="x")
```

You may also use a `lambda` (but you'll lose style points with the pythonistas):

```
setCallback(lambda param, data: myObj.callbackFunction(param, data), param="x")
```